# Should I delete migration after rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm fairly new to ruby and rails and am just getting my head around migrations.

My question is what is the best practice or right time to delete a migration after a rollback. So far what I have read is a matter of opinion whether you delete a migration after a rollback, but is there any major implications to deleting a migration when working in a team, and are there any benefits to leaving the migration file as opposed to deleting it?

In my case what would make most sense?

I had my original migrate file *20140731141350_create_users.rb*

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

To which I needed to add a *salt* column, so I created the migration *20140804125449_add_salt_colum_to_users.rb*

```
class AddSaltColumToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :salt, :string
  end
end
```

But during development I realised the *salt* column wasn't necessary and performed

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140731141350
```

Now I am left with an unused *20140804125449_add_salt_colum_to_users.rb* migrate file.

Delete or no?

Comment: If it's unneeded, delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never change your old migrations. If you realised that given column is unnecessary, write a new migration to remove it.

The reason for this is so that you can restore database schema in any point of development. If you are working in a team, the fact that you removed the migration won't change your teammates' schemas. Even more, they have no migration to revert now!

Comment: For me the one exception is if you haven't pushed that migration

Comment: Exactly, if there's a chance the mig could affect somebody, leave it there. If not, delete it, it would only complicate things.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I'm developing locally and haven't pushed anything to the team so my changes would not affect anyone, so is there a need to create ANOTHER migration to undo the migration that added the salt column? I will have then basically created 2 migrations to get me back to the original migration which seems messy to me...

Comment: @SteWoo - Another reason to keep them is for history consistency. If you ever wanted to see how your application behaved at given time you might to get unlucky and get the the history point where your application did have this field. The migration file did exist then, so you update your schema and then you need to re-revert it. However if you haven't push it yet and it is you most recent migration I see no reason to keep it. Note however that this is rather an exception than a rule.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [blog post](http://www.scottradcliff.com/post/can_i_delete_my_rails_migrations) about rails migrations.
As stated in this article:

> When I fire up a new environment, it's much easier to run rake
>   db:schema:load. And the migrations are redundant. All of that data is
>   in the schema file.

Thus I  recommend that you delete this migration if no other migration relies on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Never delete or edit your old migrations! You can bring a lot of harm to your app working with a team or even  alone.