# Where is migration status saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My question is very much related to this one [Should I delete migration after rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121347/should-i-delete-migration-after-rollback).

> I had my original migrate file *20140731141350_create_users.rb*
>
> ```
> class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
>   def change
>     create_table :users do |t|
>       t.string :email
>       t.string :password
>
>       t.timestamps
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> To which I needed to add a *salt* column, so I created the migration
>   *20140804125449_add_salt_colum_to_users.rb*
>
> ```
> class AddSaltColumToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
>   def change
>     add_column :users, :salt, :string
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> But during development I realised the *salt* column wasn't necessary
>   and performed
>
> ```
> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140731141350
> ```
>
> Now I am left with an unused
>   *20140804125449_add_salt_colum_to_users.rb* migrate file.

My question is if I don't delete this migration file, where is this "down" status of this migration saved to?  The migration file says add_column so if I run a db:migrate again how will it know that this specific file was migrated down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db:migrate:down` and `db:rollback` are similar. `down` reverts a database to a specified version, rollback - to the previous. To check is a migration applied Rails has a specific table called "schema_migrations" which stores *timestamps* of all applied migrations, so basically when you run `db:migrate:down` rails reverts the migration and remove the row from `schema_migrations`. So if you don't delete the migration file - rails will apply it in the next `db:migrate`

Comment: So if I ever run `db:migrate` I will always have to follow with `db:migrate:down` on this specific migration?

Comment: let me explain migrations like it is a dozen of paper sheet. For example, you  have 25 pages and you decided to remove page 18. So you take 7 pages (19..25 - command  db:migrate:down) away and the current state is 18 pages. Then you destroy page 18(remove the file) and put back the 7 pages. As the result you don't have page 18 anymore.